# How do I install Mantaflow into Blender 2.8.1a?

Tags: add-on, installation

I'm new to using Blender. How do I install Mantaflow into Blender 2.8.1a?

The YouTube videos I was watching say you need to download the Mantaflow experimental branch. That branch is no longer shown on Blender.org. If Mantaflow is built in to 2.8.1a how do I activate it?

When I open the physics tab it appears as if nothing has changed because there are still two separate tabs for smoke and fluid and my understanding was that for Mantaflow there is only supposed to be a fluid tab.

I downloaded the experimental branch 2.8.3 and unzipped it but that didn't seem to add Mantaflow as the two separate tabs were still under the physics setting.

Comment: Welcome! (1) See the top bar. (2) You have to download 2.8**2** from here: https://builder.blender.org/download/, Also see the release notes: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.82/Physics

Comment: Hello and  welcome. Question about this site, its use and rules belong on [meta](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com), I migrated the [part of your question about searching there](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2702/two-questions-from-a-newbie).